# How to call methods of class tornado.httpserver.HTTPserver?

Tags: python, tornado

I am learning the web framework Tornado. During the study of this framework, I found the class  `tornado.httpserver.HTTPserver`. I know how to create a constructor of this class and create instance `tornado.httpserver.HTTPserver` in `main()` function. But this class `tornado.httpserver.HTTPserver`  has 4 methods. I have not found how to use these methods.

1) `def close_all_connections(self):`

2)  `def handle_stream(self, stream, address):`

3)  `def start_request(self, server_conn, request_conn):`

4)  `def on_close(self, server_conn):`

I know that 2-4 methods are inherited from the class `tornado.tcpserver.TCPServer`
Can someone illustrate how to use these methods of a class `tornado.httpserver.HTTPserver`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These methods are used internally; you shouldn't call them yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just forgot call stack.I need to look very carefully for call stack.